# How to change multiple values with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Is it possible to change multiple table values with ONE sql query? For instance, My table named "newsletter" has a column named "received" that has an enum value which defaults to 0. When I send my newsletter out, this value gets changed to 1, so the recipient doesn't receive the same email twice. I want to make a script that when parsed will change all of the received values back to 0, so I can send another newsletter. I will provide my PHP code so far, and I have already tested the links and the database connection file so connecting to the database is no an issue.

PHP

```
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$rec_value =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE received='1'");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($rec_value);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rec_value)){
    $email = $row["email"];
    if ($numRows == 1) { 
        mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET received='0' WHERE email='$email'");
    } 
}
```

Can someone help me change my code so that it sets all received values back to 0 when this script is executed? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean something like `UPDATE newsletter SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2'...`

Comment: [sure you can. `UPDATE table SET col_x = '123', col_y = '456' WHERE col_z = 'xxx'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: if you want to `change all of the received values back to 0` then just remove your `WHERE` condition - `UPDATE newsletter SET received='0'`

Comment: You should escape the `$email`. It is possible malicious data is in DB and if it enters query you are injected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_Order_SQL_Injection

Comment: Yup what @Fred-ii- said as long as you don't put a where condition in the update it will do all rows.

Comment: Not entirely. My table has the column "received" and that column has multiple rows, which represent the different users who have subscribed to my newsletter. I am looking to set all the rows in "received" to 0 once this code is executed. @AbdoAdel

Comment: Currently your problem appears to be that `if ($numRows == 1)` check, since it will pass only if you have just one row in your resultset. So I guess if you have multiple rows, your update just isn't executed.

Comment: Oh thank you! that fixed it along with changing the string to the answer below. @OlegKomarov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean simply:

```
UPDATE newsletter SET received='0'
```

MySQL won't update those rows that are already '0' and will update rows with other values to '0'.

But if you want to be more exact and only update those rows where received is actually '1':

```
UPDATE newsletter SET received='0' WHERE received='1'
```

Comment: This works perfectly, as does the other answer, but I like the option you added to only set them to 0 when it is set to 1, which will make sure everyone gets the letter even if they sign up later.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET received='0'");` will reset all rows to 0.